# Turtle Beach not functioning properly

Tags: microphone

I have just recently bought a Turtle Beach EarForce X11 for recording videos. The only issue is, When I try to records, it records an extremely loud layer of static, and my voice, but very quietly. It also refuses to be recognized as a device in my sound settings. I am positive it is Ubuntu because I was just using it on Windows Vista a few minutes ago. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 if that helps any. Thanks a bunch!